# Button Ripple with different selected_state color

Tags: android, button, android-drawable

I have a button that it is normally colored gray and upon being pressed, it changes it's color to blue. Now I want to add an effect where it color blue starts from where I press and ripples and fills the whole button AND stays that solid color (blue). I know that I can add a ripple effect to the button and mask it but it doesn't work with selected_states. The closest that I got what the following code where if they hold down the button it will ripple but that's about it. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:color="@color/light_blue"
tools:targetApi="lollipop">
<item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/light_blue" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_selected="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/light_blue" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/sdk_dark_grey2" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had you set onClickListener to your button?

Comment: What would I do with onClickListener on my button? I'm well aware of how to use one but to what end? Could you be more specific than that? Thanks